# UWP define resource dictionary KVP globally

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

Say I wanted to define `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundSelected" Color="#ffffff" />` globally.
Note: this is a custom key for a TabView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/tabview

When I define this in App.Xaml it does not reach any of my TabViews.
When I define this in a Page, it only reaches some of my TabViews, it fails to reached heavily nested ones.

I believe this could be achieved through merged dictionaries. However, referencing a merged dictionary for each of these scopes is not very clean. And the way dictionaries are references in the source property is not very clean either.

The only think I have though of so far is creating a custom component which inherits TabView and defines the resource KVPs. Then I just need to reference the new component. I still think declaring globally would be cleaner, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> UWP define resource dictionary KVP globally

Thanks for your interesting, for this scenario, the better way is custom `TabView` and edit the default `TabViewItemHeaderBackgroundSelected` within the default style. And you could find the default style [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/TabView/TabView.xaml#L7).